# Using the ODR register directly On STM32

Tags: c, stm32, gpio

Modify the code for WriteLED() to use the ODR register directly. The code should read the current
value of the register and then write back a modified value depending on what LEDs are to be turns
on or off.

Example Code Given to me

```
void HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIO_TypeDef* GPIOx, uint16_t GPIO_Pin)
{
/* Check the parameters */
assert_param(IS_GPIO_PIN(GPIO_Pin));
GPIOx->ODR ˆ= GPIO_Pin;
}
```

Code That Needs to be Altered

```
WriteLED (uint8_t LED, uint8_t State)
{
  // Check for correct state
 if ((State != LED_OFF) && (State != LED_ON))
  {
    return;
  }

  // Turn on/off the LED
  switch (LED)
    {
    case 'L':
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin (LD4_GPIO_Port, LD4_Pin, State);
      break;
    case 'T':
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin (LD3_GPIO_Port, LD3_Pin, State);
      break;
    case 'B':
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin (LD6_GPIO_Port, LD6_Pin, State);
      break;
    case 'R':
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin (LD5_GPIO_Port, LD5_Pin, State);
      break;
    }

  return;
}
```

What should the above code look like when outputting to ODR register

Comment: At https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic you will find it states:  _"Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."_.  You have provided neither, which makes it look like a homework cheat rather then a legitimate request for assistance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand C bitwise operations. The three are `^` (exclusive OR), `&` (bitwise and), `|` (bitwise or)

To clear a bit
`GPIO->ODR &= ~pin_mask;`

To set a bit
`GPIO->ODR |= pin_mask;`

This should give you enough information.

Comment: Hey Thank-you so much for the answer , any chance you could show me an example with the code above ?